# Criteria when bigger number of functions can be obtained from smaller number

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

It is known that
$$
    A_1(x_1, x_2) = \partial \varphi(x_1, x_2)/\partial x_1,
$$
$$
    A_2(x_1, x_2) = \partial \varphi(x_1, x_2)/\partial x_2
$$
holds if and only if
$$
    \partial A_1/\partial x_2 =     \partial A_2/\partial x_1.
$$

What would be criteria on $A_i$ in a more general case:
$$
    A_i(x) = F_i(B_j(x), \partial B_k(x)/\partial x)
$$
where $x = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ and number of functions $A_i$ is bigger than the number of functions $B_k$.